# Print labels with Google cloud print and apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-print

I what to write a Google apps script for a Google sheet that sends labels to a Google cloud printer for printer. Is this possible, and how will the script look?

Comment: [Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script+google-cloud-print) ?

Comment: Can you please describe your workflow?? Include Client-side language serverside language and your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I use Zapier for this. I've set up zaps that prins to Google Cloud print every time an attendee in Eventbrite registers, or every time a Gravity forms is filled or whenever a spread sheet row is created/updated in google sheets. No coding..except a little html to get the label to look better.